# Java Buttons Array from Resultset

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a simple Queue Kiosk front screen, so I need to dinamically list buttons from a sql query resultset, I have a ´services´ table, with n options the customer can choice. I already have some code but just with a local array. I cannot find the way to list the buttons from the resultset.

```
    package queuefront;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class IGrafica {

    private JFrame frame;
    public int index=0;



    public IGrafica(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        configureFrame();
        inicializarIG();

    }

    public void configureFrame(){
        frame=new JFrame();

frame.setSize(400, 500);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.setSize(800, 600);
        //frame.setBounds(100,100,400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10)); //
    }


    public void inicializarIG(){


String[] buttons = {"Operación 1", "Operación 2", "Operación 3", "Operación 4"};
//int[] id={1,2,3,4};
System.out.println("longitud del array= "+ buttons.length );
        JButton [] botones = new JButton [buttons.length];

        //Loop to set up buttons and add the mouseListener
        for (index = 0; index < botones.length; index++) {
            botones[index] = new JButton(buttons[index]);


            //Set up each listener 
           botones[index].addActionListener(new MyActionListener(index));

            //Add the button
            frame.getContentPane().add(botones[index]);

        }       
    }

private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private int index;

    public MyActionListener(int index) {
        this.index = index+1;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try { new Guardar().guardar(database.Conexion.obtener(), index);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      System.out.println("Ha surgido un error y no se ha podido guardar el registro.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      System.out.println("Ha surgido un error y no se ha podido guardar el registro.");
    }
        System.out.println("index is: " + index);
        System.out.println("Action Command is: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }


    }

    public void visualizate(){
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        IGrafica window = new IGrafica();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                window.visualizate();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

// class array

```
package queuefront;
import java.sql.*;

public class array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try { new array().Buscar(database.Conexion.obtener());
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      System.out.println("Ha surgido un error y no se ha podido guardar el registro.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      System.out.println("Ha surgido un error y no se ha podido guardar el registro.");
    }

    }
    public static void Buscar(java.sql.Connection conexion) throws SQLException{
    try
    {
      java.sql.PreparedStatement consulta = conexion.prepareStatement("select service from services");

      java.sql.ResultSet rs = consulta.executeQuery();
      String[] arr = null;
     while (rs.next()) {
                String em = rs.getString("service");
               arr = em.split("\n");
               for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
                   System.out.println(arr[i]);
               }
            }
    }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd better use `List` instead of array because `List` is resizable. Also there is no mention of `ResultSet` in your code

Comment: My mistake, below is the code where I get the resultset.